# Inject an EJB into JUnit test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, ejb

I defined an **EJB** as follows:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    private Boo boo;

    public void doSomething() {
        boo.doOther();
    }

}
```

And:

```
@Named
@RequestScope
public class Boo {

    public void doOther() {
        // I do, I do...
    }

}
```

I would like to inject the `Foo` EJB into a **JUnit test class**:

```
import org.junit.*

public class FooTest {

    @EJB
    private Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void doSomethingTest() {
        foo.doSomething();
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

... But this code returns a `NullPointerException`.

What's wrong? How can I properly define that test by using **Java EE CDI**?

Comment: You need a container to run your tests. You could take a look at http://arquillian.org, or inject the bean in your test yourself, using reflection or constructor wiring.

Comment: You could try using an embedded EJB container. Take a look at the [following example](https://dzone.com/articles/bootstrapping-cdi-several) and at the following [Oracle example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/embeddedContainerDemo/EmbeddedContainerDemo.html).